# SetState from another componenet

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie in react and I want to display the Alert when an Error occurs.
On my page, I have this snippet

```
      {err ? <ErrorAlert
      error={err}                  
      /> : null}
```

and I can call my Alert Component

```
const ErrorAlert = ({ error, visible }) => {

    
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);


    return (
        <>

            <Alert

                show={show}
                animate={{
                    mount: { y: 0 },
                    unmount: { y: 100 },
                }}

                dismissible={{
                    onClose: () => {
                        setShow(false)                        
                    },
                }}

            >
                A dismissible alert with custom animation.
            </Alert>

        </>
    );
}
```

When I clock on the icon I can close my component and setState to false.
When another error Occurs, my Component is not visible. How Can I handle the state from the outside or something like that, check if the state is visible and if not enable it?

I don't click on Alert, the alert needs to receive a "notification" from another context

Comment: You can do something like this

    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(error) //error is props

Comment: You can use the seemingly unused prop `visible` to control it. Whenever error occurs, set it to true and pass it. Your `ErrorAlert` component will re-render whenever its props change.

Comment: @cSharp `const [show, setShow] = React.useState(visible);` in tat way I have the same behaviour

Comment: @monkeyUser if you're using the prop as the initial value for a state (which then controls the behaviour of the component) and you want the component to re-render on prop change, you can use a useEffect like: `useEffect(() => { setShow(visible); }, [visible]);`.

Comment: @cSharp i added `const [show, setShow] = React.useState(visible);
    useEffect(() => { setShow(visible); }, [visible]);`and `<ErrorAlert visible={true} />` but when I close alert I can't see again if error occurs

Comment: @monkeyUser are you passing the correct boolean whenever you're getting an error? If you're passing just `visible={true}`, it's not going to update again.

Comment: in that way, if I close the alert and re-do the same action I can't see the alert again because the visible is still true. I can change the prop to false only if the errors disapper `{err ? <ErrorAlert errors={err} visible={true}  /> : null}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252432/discussion-between-csharp-and-monkeyuser).

Comment: Please post your solution in the answer section below and remove it from the question section above.

Answer (score 0):

-- Solution --

Thanks to @cSharp

````
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(!!errors);
    useEffect(() => { setShow(!!errors) }, [errors])

    return (
        <>

            <Alert
                show={show}
                color="red"
                animate={{
                    mount: { y: 0 },
                    unmount: { y: 100 },
                }}

                dismissible={{
                    onClose: () => setShow(false),
                    action: (
                        <Button variant="text" color="white" size="sm">
                            Close
                        </Button>
                    ),
                }}>
                <div>
                    {Array.isArray(errors.message) && errors.message.length > 0 ? (
                        <ul>
                            {errors.message.map((error) => (
                                <li key={error}>{error}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    ) : errors.message}
                </div>
            </Alert>

        </>
    );
}

export default ErrorAlert```
````